# Display rows if one item is present in column of multiple values of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

Suppose I have dataframe like -

```
uni_id country_name scholarship timeperiod type course_name
    1          UK            1           4   UG     Btech;Bcom;BArts
    1          UK            0           2   PG     Mba
    2          UK            1           3   UG     Bcom;xyx
```

Now how do display all the rows with course name == 'Bcom' i.e.

```
uni_id country_name scholarship timeperiod type course_name
    1          UK            1           4   UG     Bcom
    2          UK            1           3   UG     Bcom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the string, then keep only the duplicated values and use it to reindex the dataframe and assign the new values:

```
s = df['course_name'].str.split(';').explode()
s2 = s[s.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)

out = df.loc[s2.index].assign(course_name=s2)
```

Output:

```
   uni_id country_name  scholarship  timeperiod type course_name
0       1           UK            1           4   UG        Bcom
2       2           UK            1           3   UG        Bcom
```

Without intermediate `s2`:

```
s = (df['course_name'].str.split(';').explode()
     .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)]
     .groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)
    )

out = df.loc[s.index].assign(course_name=s)
```

Comment: Any way we directly check the course name, instead of creating s2

Comment: @Prakket you can use a function or loc, let me update, but you need at least one intermediate (for clarity)